# VBS determine number of records in SQL table

Tags: sql, vbscript

How do I determine the number of records in a SQL table and then save that value in variable?

Comment: this is the closest i got:  num_rows = "Select COUNT(*) FROM recepti_sol

Comment: Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: and what is wrong with my question?

Comment: You will probably get better responses and less down votes if you 1) briefly explain your goal 2) post the code you have tried 3) explain what is it doing wrong, including any errors. Otherwise, some will take it as a "give me the codez" request - whether that is how you meant it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to access the db:

1. execute a simple `SELECT count(0) FROM myTable` query.
2. access the resultset (if not empty) and read the returned value.

Not tested code:

```
Dim conn, rs, recordsCount
recordsCount = -1

'initialize the connection
set conn = ...

'run the query and retrieve the results
set rs = conn.execute("SELECT count(0) as cnt FROM myTable")
if not rs.EOF then
  recordsCount = cint(rs("cnt"))
end if


'cleanup
rs.close
conn.close

set rs = nothing
set conn = nothing
```

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*)" returns a Long (or better), the downcast to Int is dangerous.

Comment: Does count(*) always return a int64? doesn't it depend on the file datatype? Really, I am curious. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Obviously the return type depends on the DBMS, the Driver, and the language, but the count will be Long or better; so don't down cast it to a signed 16 bit integer (CInt()).

Answer (score 1):

Three methods to get the size of a recordset/result of a query:

```
Option Explicit

' simple way to get a connection
Dim oDb : Set oDb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oDb.Open "dsn=NWIND"

' execute & !obtain result! of "SELECT COUNT()" query
WScript.Echo "Select Count(*):", oDb.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products").Fields(0).Value

' trying to use recordcount (fails, because non-static rs)
WScript.Echo "RecordCount (A):", oDb.Execute("SELECT * FROM Products").RecordCount

' use recordcount with static rs
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Dim oRs : Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM Products", oDb, adOpenStatic
WScript.Echo "RecordCount (B):", oRs.RecordCount

' get rows from query and use UBound()
Dim aData : aData = oDb.Execute("SELECT * FROM Products").GetRows()
WScript.Echo "GetRows():", UBound(aData, 2) + 1

oDb.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 04.vbs
Select Count(*): 77
RecordCount (A): -1
RecordCount (B): 77
GetRows(): 77
```

Use the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to learn more about these strategies.

Comment: If you only wants the count and nothing else, everything but "select count(0) from table" seems wasteful.

No need to fetch data you don't want to use.