# Saving value from SQL statement to VBS variable

Tags: sql, vbscript

As a beginner in SQL and VBS programming i encounter the following problem. I want to determine number of rows in a SQL table, save that value to VBS variable and then use it in a for loop. 
I've came up with the following code, but it's obvious that i'm missing something here and i'm basically stuck.

```
num_rows = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM recepti_sol"

For y = 0 To "num_rows"
```

Plese help me complete the code.
Thank you for you time and efforts!

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question from a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688148/vbs-determine-number-of-records-in-sql-table

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
This is an example for an sql server
Take it as the most simple to run, but not to make it productive as it has clear text passwords.  Anyway it can fail depending on your sqlserver configuration, but you can fix with a diferent connection string, so, again, read about them

```
set conn= CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Driver={SQLServer};Server=Your_Server_Name;Database=Your_Database_Name;Uid=sa;Pwd=saPassword;"
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "SELECT COUNT(id) as num_rows FROM recepti_sol", conn
For y = 1 To rs("num_rows")
  ...
  ...
next
rs.close
conn.close
set rs = nothing
set conn = nothing
```

Comment: Your loop will fail: 0 .. num_rows == num_rows + 1.

Comment: Assume num_rows == 2: your loop will repeat 3 times: 0, 1, 2

Comment: i can't seem to find path to my databese. I'm using SQL 2008

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner  yes, so?  can't you imagine a task inside the loop that needs an extra loop? I will fix, but is not relevant now

Comment: @LuisSiquot - if you really think your trap for learners is a feature, then please add comment.

Comment: @user1758545, sql server 2008 needs other connection string see [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008). give me a moment to fix the code

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I am not trying to trap anybody. Please, don't be rude and I will do the same.

Comment: I get an error that function or sub is not defined on line: Set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13688782/603855) - use the .GetRows() method of the Recordset object and work with the returned two-dimensional arry.